# iostat how do I set up a logging

Tags: linux, performance, iostat

Hi there I am pretty newbie in servers, would appreciate your help.
How do I set up an iostat logging? as my Disk IO spikes strange at some random time to very high levels.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

IOSTAT provides stats for individual block devices, and won't tell you which process is actually driving IO. However, it's useful for characterizing your I/O access patterns. You can generate a large log-file with this command:

```
iostat -x sda -c 2 -t > stats.log
```

This will monitor sda (-x sda) every 2 seconds (-c 2) with a timestamp (-t). The logfile is not pretty, but it'll get you there.

Comment: "...which process is actually driving..." is there one which can tell me and I can log the history to find out?
for seeing the pattern of io spikes I can see it in linode dashboard. But really need to find out the issue and eliminate it. thanks.

Comment: @Simple For that, read this question: http://serverfault.com/questions/25032/linux-disk-io-load-breakdown-by-filesystem-path-and-or-process